# Git checkout branch doesn't change working directory

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question, as I am new to git.  One of my coworkers was working on a feature in a branch called "rotation."  I wanted to make use of the code he wrote, so I ran `git checkout rotation`.  The main difference between `master` and `rotation` branches is that the rotation branch has an extra subdirectory titled `rotation/`.  However, after running git checkout, this subdirectory did not show up in my working directory.  How do I get this subdirectory to show up?  I did some googling and found that git doesn't make changes to your working directory when you git checkout a branch if those changes would conflict with tracked changes in your working directory.  However, this is not the case here, at least for the `rotation/` subdirectory, as it does not even exist in `master`.  So why doesn't this subdirectory show up?  How do I get it to?

Comment: Have you fetched/pulled the latest commits from that branch?

Comment: Git does not version directories. If there are no files within the directory, it will not be available when you checkout the branch.

Comment: Please describe the different repositories involved here. Do you and your coworker each have your own repo? Is there a central repo where you push changes to? Are there any files in the new `rotation/` subdirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `git pull origin rotation`?
The form should be `git pull <remote> <branchname>`.

Comment: this won't mess up anything in the rotation branch?

Comment: No. You are pulling the files from the branch to your local machine.

Answer (score 7):

Simply checking out the branch isn't enough to get remote changes to your machine. You must use `git pull` or `git fetch`.

Here is a 
[useful diagram you can use as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2At5.png).

Answer (score 3):

In the following comments, I assume that there are three repositories, your own local repo, your coworker's repo, and a central repo. It sounds like you already have a local branch named `rotation`. If your coworker pushed her `rotation` branch to the central repo, you need to update that branch with your coworker's changes:

```
$ git checkout rotation
$ git pull origin rotation
```

Note, that if your coworker only created a directory without adding any files, then she cannot commit it. Git does not track directories themselves. Instead, it tracks files and stores extra information about the directory where the file belongs.